# How can I create a new list in my for loop whenever my else statement is triggered

Tags: python, list, for-loop, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape articles from a website, but each article has multiple paragraphs which I have to concatenate so they can go into a single cell. So in my code, whenever the "Permalink" appears then I want the for loop to be triggered so that the next article's paragraphs are saved into a new single cell.

How can I make an "infinite" for loop which creates a new list when the else statement is triggered? I understand that my code below has some issues, such as the first line being outside of the for loop, but I was getting errors otherwise.

Thanks for the help!

```
paragraph = []
for content in specific_area.findAll('p'):
    if content.text.strip() != "Permalink":
    paragraph.append(content.text.strip())
    else:
      continue

paragraph = '\n'.join(paragraph)
print(paragraph)
```

Answer (score 2):

The following code will place the resulting articles in a list called `articles`.

It basically starts with filling up `current_article` with paragraphs until we reach the permalink. Then the `current_article` list gets joined and placed in `articles`. `current_article` then gets cleaned for the next article.

```
articles = []
current_article = []
for content in specific_area.findAll('p'):
    entry = content.text.strip()
    if entry == "Permalink":
        articles.append('\n'.join(current_article))
        current_article = []
    else:
        current_article.append(entry)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! how would I be able to output each "current article" row by row?

Comment: Depends where/how you want to output it. Each article is basically a string now in the `articles` list. So you can do something as simple as `for article in articles: print(article)`. It's possible I misunderstand what you mean with row by row though.

Answer (score 1):

Accumulate the result somewhere else, like this

```
result = []
paragraph = []
for content in specific_area.findAll('p'):
    if content.text.strip() != "Permalink":
        paragraph.append(content.text.strip())
    else:
      result.append(paragraph)
      paragraph = []
      continue

paragraph = '\n'.join(result)
print(paragraph)
```